# Фунция совпадений строк

Tags: php

Сори за такой заголовок, вообщем ищу функцию строк, где функция ищет совпадения типо вот такого

```
if (функция("текст","кс")) { $fun == true } else { $fun == false } в этом случае результат true
```

искал на php.su, но функций много, среди них не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strpos()](http://php.su/functions/?strpos) тебе в помощь

---

**UPD**

```
if (strpos("текст","кс")===false) 
{ 
    $fun == false
} 
else 
{ 
    $fun == true
}
```

Comment: Что значит Возвращает позицию первого вхождения подстроки ? и видел так же функцию, где написано Возвращает позицию последнего вхождения подстроки

Comment: strpos("текст","кс") возвратит 2, добавил код в ответ

---

strpos("текст","т") вернет 0 - позицию (нольбазированную), в которой первый раз встретится указанная подстрока. 
strpos(), strrpos(), stripos(), strripos() используются, если надо узнать позицию подстроки, в данном случае нужно только наличие, потому не существенно, какая функция используется (разве что какие-то технические аспекты могут играть роль)

Answer (score 0):

Здесь варианта два:

Либо ты хочешь найти хоть одно вхождение подстроки в строке, т.е. SFPWOFO  strpos() тебе найдет и SFPWOFO и WOFO и PWO

А если ты хочешь сравнить их, т.е. ABC = ABC то ...
то тут в помощь функция из рода strcasecmp = сверяет строки без учета регистра

Hallo = HALLO = HAlLo = hAlLO

Answer (score 0):

Еще есть похожесть строк

```
levenshtein ()
similar_text ()
```